# How to create a automatic 'split' of records in PHP with SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am working on a PHP forum and i wanted to know how i could split my records into a few diffirent pages or sections of the webpage with a userinput so when a user inputs 'pokemon' he/she would retrieve like a 1000 records how would i be able to split that records automaticly through a few pages or sections in the webpage?

right now i have this code:

```
 <?php
    $query = $_POST['query'];

    $selected = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","forumdb") or die("");

    $result = mysqli_query($selected, "SELECT * FROM threads WHERE name LIKE '%$query%' ORDER BY name");
<table> 
   <tr>
      <td><center><p>{$row['name']}</p></center></td>
   </tr>
</table>
?>
```

how can i transform this page to one where only 25 could be displayed and the rest is displayed on other pages (automaticly)

Comment: It's called pagination and it does not happen automatically, you'd have to write the code to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i transform this page to one where only 25 could be displayed and the rest is displayed on other pages (automaticly)

**Pagination** is what you're trying to achieve here. And as @jeroen said, *it does not happen automatically, you'd have to write the code to make it happen*. I've already answered several questions on this topic, and even wrote a generic script for the same. So **the solution** to your problem is this:

- Go to https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination, download `pagination.php` file and include it into your project directory, like this:

  ```
  require_once('pagination.php');
  ```
- Create an instance of `Pagination` class, with appropriate driver, like this:

  ```
  $pg = new Pagination('mysqli', 'localhost', 'root', '', 'forumdb');
  ```
- Set pagination parameters using `setPaginationParameters()` method, like this,

  ```
  $pg->setPaginationParameters(25, 5);
  ```
- Call `getResult()` method of `Pagination` class to display rows based on the URL query `?page=X`, like this,

  ```
  $param = '%' . $query . '%';
  $resultSet = $pg->getResult('SELECT * FROM threads WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY name', array($param), $_GET, 'page');

  echo '<table>';
  foreach($resultSet as $row){
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td><center><p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p></center></td>
      </tr>
     <?
  }
  echo '</table>';
  ```
- Finally, display pagination links using `getPaginationLinks()` method, like this,

  ```
  $pgLinks = $pg->getPaginationLinks();
  if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['prev']){
      /* previous pages are available */
      echo '&laquo; ';
  }
  if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks['links'])){
      /* show pagination links */
      foreach($pgLinks['links'] as $link){
          echo '<a href="yourPage.php?page='.$link.'">'.$link.'</a> ';
      }
  }
  if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['next']){
      /* next pages are available */
      echo '&raquo;';
  }
  ```

**Note:** Don't forget to change **yourPage.php** with your page.

Here's **the complete code**,

```
<?php

    require_once('pagination.php');

    $pg = new Pagination('mysqli', 'localhost', 'root', '', 'forumdb');
    $pg->setPaginationParameters(25, 5);

    $param = '%' . $query . '%';
    $resultSet = $pg->getResult('SELECT * FROM threads WHERE name LIKE ? ORDER BY name', array($param), $_GET, 'page');

    echo '<table>';
    foreach($resultSet as $row){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><center><p><?php echo $row['name']; ?></p></center></td>
        </tr>
       <?
    }
    echo '</table>';

    $pgLinks = $pg->getPaginationLinks();
    if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['prev']){
        /* previous pages are available */
        echo '&laquo; ';
    }
    if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks['links'])){
        /* show pagination links */
        foreach($pgLinks['links'] as $link){
            echo '<a href="yourPage.php?page='.$link.'">'.$link.'</a> ';
        }
    }
    if(is_array($pgLinks) && count($pgLinks) && $pgLinks['next']){
        /* next pages are available */
        echo '&raquo;';
    }
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:** Go through the **Usage** documentation if you need any further clarification on the usage of this script.

Comment: Thx for sharing Rajdeep. Will take a look when I get a chance. +1

Comment: Sure @Drew , I'll look forward to your valuable opinion and suggestions.:-)

Comment: Thanks for answering! it worked i am glad you shared it.

Comment: @A.Mousavi Glad I could help. Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Pester me once a week until I review it :p I had to search on `pagination` to refind it. Better yet bookmark right?